# Generate/ duplicate HTML with PHP

Tags: php, html, code-generation, code-duplication

I want to duplicate an image tag with PHP.

'amount' is the amount of rows in my table.

My code:

```
while($counter < $amount){
    echo ('<li><img src"Login/images/'.$files[0].'" width="600px;"></li>');
    $counter++;
}
```

Comment: So what is your problem? Seems like the code works fine.

Comment: The problem is that there is no image

Comment: Are you sure that images are in that folder and the path is correct?

Comment: I don't see an `=` between the attribute name (i.e. `src`) and the path of the image file.

Comment: Are you displaying always the same image (`$files[0]`)?

Comment: Works now. Thanks Kemal Fadillah!!

Answer (score -1):

According to the comments I came up with a few solutions:

1. Check if $counter has been initialized (`$counter = 0;`)
2. Check if $amount is not 0
3. Look at the output of the script and check if the output has been written
4. Check if $files[0] is not an empty string